# how to add editText in a custom list adapter

Tags: android, listview, runtime, android-edittext

I want to add a row of 3 editTexts whenever the user removes focus from the last editText of the above row. I have tried various methods like inflating an individual linearLayout every time the user removes focus from the last editText. The problem in this method is I get a large number of linearLayouts to deal with which is not so efficient. Somebody suggested me to us custom list view but I don't know anything about it. Please help

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom list view. Look [here](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429).

In `listview_item_row.xml`, instead of using ImageView and TextView, you have to create a LinearLayout with 3 EditText. And finally, you have to create your own adapter like `WeatherAdapter.java` and inflate your 3 EditText.